# Firebase rule to allow particular user to login 'n' number of times a day

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication, pyrebase

I've created an app in python with the help of pyrebase4, I'm able to register a user and allow only email verified users to login.

I want to limit a particular user to login 'n' number of times a day. Is there any security rule that could limit this? A rule which can check the number of time that particular user has logged-in in a day?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication doesn't have any configurable way to limit how often a user can sign in. In fact, the recommended flow is that you require the user to sign in as infrequently as possible, and the SDKs persist the authentication state between app restarts/page reloads precisely to prevent the user from having to sign in each time they open the app.

It sounds more like this is an app-specific use-case, where you want the user to only be able to use your app a certain number of times per day.

The simplest way I could think of implementing that is to increment a counter for the current date every time the user starts the app, for example in one of the Firebase databases. You'd then also check the value on startup, and show a message to the user shown when they've exceeded the limit.

Once you store the counter in the database, you can write security rules that prevent the user from accessing other data once the counter is above your limit. And this lack of access to the data would then presumably make the app unusable to them.

Answer (score 0):

Define an intenger MaxPerDay inside the user object.
let's say the max amount of entrance to your app is 5 times per day

```
{
   "rules": {
   "users": {
      "$user": {
        ".read": "data.child('MaxPerDay').val() == 5"
     }
    }
 } 
}
```